# How can I inject DBContext to HTTPModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, httpmodule

I have a problem with `DBContext` while creating httpmodule that uses `Entity Framework`.
I'd like to inject `DBContext` into the `httpmodule` like injecting dependency in `constructor`.
Is there any solution for me?

in `MyHTTPModule`

```
    public class MyHTTPModule: IHttpModule
    {
    ...
        public void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication Application = (HttpApplication)sender;
            HttpContext Context = Application.Context;

            string filepath= Context.Request.FilePath;
            MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext();
            var file = db.file.FirstOrDefault(r => r.filename == filepath);
    ...
        }
    }
```

What I want is injecting dbcontext into httpmodule like:

```
    public class MyHTTPModule: IHttpModule
    {
        private MyDBContext db;
        public MyHTTPModule(MyDBContext dbcontext)
        {
            db = dbcontext;
        }
    ...
        public void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication Application = (HttpApplication)sender;
            HttpContext Context = Application.Context;
            string filepath= Context.Request.FilePath;
            var file = db.file.FirstOrDefault(r => r.filename == filepath);
    ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657473/ioc-dependency-injection-into-custom-http-module-how-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found simple solution for this problem using [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html).

Installed 3 NuGet packages. `(Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, SimpleInjector, SimpleInjector.Integration.Web)`

and created interface for `MyDBContext`

in `Global.asax.cs`

```
private static Container container;

public static Container Container
{
    get { return container ?? (container = RegisterAndVerifyContainer()); }
}

private static Container RegisterAndVerifyContainer()
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

    container.Register<IDBContext, MyDBContext>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

    container.Verify();

    return container;
}
```

in `MyDBContext`

```
public partial class MyDBContext: DbContext, IDBContext
{
    public MyDBContext() : base("name=MyDBContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<file> file{ get; set; }
}

public interface IDBContext : IDisposable
{
    DbSet<file> file { get; set; }
}
```

in `MyHTTPModule`

```
private IDBContext DBContext;
public MyHTTPModule()
{
    DBContext = Global.Container.GetInstance<IDBContext>();
}
```